# Appending a cloned row of a table to a specified position on table

Tags: javascript, html

```
function CreateInterface(){
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=
       '<form action="?" method="get" onsubmit=" return validate(this)">' +
       '<table id="dataTable" summary="" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" border="0">' +
       '<tr id="tablerow">' + '<td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td> '+
       '<th>Userid   : </th>' + '<td ><input name="userid" type="text" class="text" value="" maxlength="10" /></td>' +
       '</tr>' + '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">'+
       '<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow()" />' +
       '<INPUT type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delRow()" />' +
       '<input type="submit" value="submit" />'+'</td></tr>' +
       '</table>' +
       '</form>';
}

function addRow(){

  var clnNode=document.getElementById("tablerow").cloneNode(true);  
  document.getElementById("dataTable").appendChild(clnNode);
}
```

This is my code , i want this cloned node to be inserted above the buttons. In fact this code is not working, i.e. node is not getting added to table. Please help me solve this

Comment: When or how are these functions being called?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot:No, i have to use javascript :(

Comment: @nayish ::CreateInterface() is working fine first time row is showing with buttons .Now when i press Add added row is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `id="tablerow"` as duplicate ids will cause malformed HTML.
Change <strike>`<tr id="tablerow">`</strike> in your string to just `<tr>`

Script

```
function addRow() {
    var referenceNodes = document.getElementById("dataTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
    //-2 because last row is button row
    var referenceNode = referenceNodes[referenceNodes.length - 2];
    var newNode = referenceNode.cloneNode(true);
    newNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked = false;
    newNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value = "";
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/wbFMm/

Comment: Another problem in this code , when i write something in the input box and the click on ADD it add the row but with the same data that is written in it ....I need a blank row without anything written in Input ...

Comment: Done i have added two line                                        var clnAttr=clnNode.getElementsByTagName("input");
 clnAttr[1].value=''; It worked , let mw know if some other clean method is there !!!! thx

Comment: i have done almost the same work around. dont forget about the check box

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `insertBefore` and pass `lastChild` as second parameter to insert the cloned row just above buttons.

```
function addRow(){
    var table=document.getElementById("dataTable")
    var clnNode=document.getElementById("tablerow").cloneNode(true);  
    table.insertBefore(clnNode,table.lastChild);
}
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/8KYum/10/

As for code is not working, you are not calling `CreateInterface` from anywhere. Set it up to run on `onLoad` and things will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your using the same ID for several elements (`tableRow`). An id must be unique on an html page. As seen in [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

A better solution would be to have only one row with the ID and every time you clone the row simply remove the id from the clone.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code. I've just tweaked your existing addRow function

```
function addRow(){

  var clnNode=document.getElementById("tablerow").cloneNode(true);  
  tableObj = document.getElementById("dataTable");
  tbodyObj = document.getElementById("dataTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
  tableObj.insertBefore(clnNode, tbodyObj)
}
```

Comment: This worked for me - the only thing I did slightly different, is that I also removed the ID attribute after I'd cloned it to ensure I've only got one on the page using the following immediately after the cloneNode(true) statement. -- clnNode.removeAttribute("id"); --